# How to generate 5 different random number and must include at least 1 negative number (asp.net webforms)

Tags: webforms

I want to generate 5 random number in the text box and at least include 1 with negative number

Comment: pick a random negative number, assign it to a random textbox, and then use your existing code for the rest of them?

Comment: not sure why you're using a guid to initialize random, but if you declared it as a class field, it would likely resolve the problem you were encountering.

Comment: If you are generating 10 random numbers, generate at least one more (between 0 and 9).  Generate that number first.  Use it to decide which number you will make random.  If it comes up "4", pick the fourth number and force it to be negative (if the number is zero, do it again).  Be aware that as soon as you start mucking deterministically with a sequence of random numbers, they become less random.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply pick a random negative number, then assign it to a random textbox, and then use your code to populate the other textboxes:

```
private Random rand = new Random();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBoxes = new List<TextBox> { TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5 };

    // Pick a random negative number and assign it to a random textbox
    var negNumber = rand.Next(-100, 0).ToString();
    var randomTextboxIndex = rand.Next(textBoxes.Count);
    textBoxes[randomTextboxIndex].Text = negNumber;

    // Assign the other textboxes random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Count; i++)
    {
        if (i == randomTextboxIndex) continue;
        textBoxes[i].Text = rand.Next(-100, 101).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's like Rufus' code but a bit more succinct:

```
private Random rand = new Random();

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBoxes = new [] { TextBox1, TextBox2, TextBox3, TextBox4, TextBox5 };

    // Pick a random textbox that shall be negative
    var negTb = rand.Next(textBoxes.Length);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < textBoxes.Length; i++)
        textBoxes[i].Text = rand.Next(-100, i == negTb ? 0 : 101).ToString();
    
}
```

Decide randomly which tb shall be negative and then when you're assigning, make the upper limit of random for that indexed tb to be 0 instead of 101